# Bolded text in HTML reverting to a different font

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I am encountering an issue with the font in a webpage I am making.

I have a font called Gotham for the main copy and I have it in the CSS as:

```
body * {
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: Gotham;
}
```

I have also got a separate font used just for the company logo. I have added them in using font-face as below:

```
@font-face {font-family: neosans; src: url("../fonts/neo_sans/NeoSan");}
@font-face {font-family: neosans; src: url("../fonts/neo_sans/NeoSans-Bold"); font-weight: bold;}
```

Basically I am wanting to make company logo by using the neosans font as follows:

**Company**Logo

So I have this:

```
<h1><b>Company</b>Logo</h1>
```

And CSS as:

```
.splash-title h1 {font-family: neosans; font-size: 6.5em; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

But for some reason, the bolded word in the company logo is reverting to the Gotham font in bold, not the neosans. I initially thought it may be the NeoSans-Bold file, or font-family screwing something up and therefore making it Gotham, but I changed the Body * font family to neosans and it the logo looks as I want it to.

Comment: Where is your file-ending inside the `url` ? Is it a `NeoSan.woff, NeoSan.ttf` or `NeoSan.eot` ?

Comment: It is a FFIL, but I tried it and it didn't do anything.

Comment: Hm, you could try to convert it to a more common font-format, I'm not sure if any of the browsers are supporting the `FFIL` format. (Nothing found on **[CanIuse](http://caniuse.com/)**)

Comment: The file seems to work as I tested it by making the body font as neosans, then it bolded fine, I am thinking the problem may be something else.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I have fixed this.

Originally I had:

```
body * {
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: Gotham;
}
```

I have just taken the Asterisk * out of the body in CSS and that seems to have done the trick. I have just been reading about it and I must have used it without fully understanding what it does.

Comment: i believe that : .`splash-title h1 b` would have override `body *` ;), but good point to remove the asterix selector once you do not fully understand its purpose and if needed